# Tar "mode" flag is being ignored

Tags: command-line-interface, tar

I try to tar a file and set the permissions to 666 using the `mode` flag. But whatever permission I set, it is simply being ignored. Command:

`tar  xvzf backup.tar.gz --mode=666 -C /home/user/`

Till all files show up with their original permissions.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page for GNU tar:

```
 --mode=CHANGES
       force (symbolic) mode CHANGES for added files
```

The key word there is *symbolic*. You've used numeric permissions. The corresponding symbolic mode for `666` is `a=rw`.

However, even if you make this change it will probably not do what you want because it will remove the execute flag from directories. Maybe what you really want is `a+rw` which will only add flags, not remove them.

Comment: Thanks, but this has no effect. Also, from the same manual: "permissions can be specified either as an octal number or as symbolic permissions, like with chmod". So even the numbers should work. But neither do. Tested under Ubuntu and CentOS - neither work.

Comment: Maybe the "p" flag is required too during extraction.

Comment: I just realized you were using --mode during extraction. Isn't it just for creation of the tar?

Comment: I did not read anywhere if this is for creation only. But it would explain my problem. However, I can not change the way the tar is created, only the way it is extracted. Is there a way to extract with certain permissions?

Comment: You could always extract it and then follow up with a "chmod" command (either recursive or inside a "find")

Comment: Due to certain settings I can not "chmod" files, I can only tar. So I hoped I could change the permissions this way. But it looks like it's not possible. I'll look for another option then.

Comment: You could extract the tar, create a new tarball with the `--mode` flag, then extract it again.

Comment: Nice! But of a indirect solution but a solution nevertheless!